# How to create "floating button" in Android?

Tags: android, layout

I have activity with ScrollView including some content, and also button. I want to do my button (@+id/buttonSubmit) visible always on the bottom of the screen, independent scrolling content. Have any idea?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cyan50">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            // scroll content here

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
                style="@style/ButtonLight"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_medium_margin"
                android:text="@string/submit_changes"/>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your root layout to FrameLayout and put the button to the same level as the scrollview and add `android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"` if you want to make sure it will positioned in the bottom. The XML should be like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cyan50">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.brut.truckers.ui.activity.ProfileActivity">

            <LinearLayout style="@style/LayoutTitle">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewDefault"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/trucker_name" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTruckerName"
                style="@style/EditTextDefault"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_small_margin"
                android:hint="@string/tap_to_edit" />


            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_big_margin">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewDefault"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/trucking_company" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTruckerCompany"
                style="@style/EditTextDefault"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_small_margin"
                android:hint="@string/tap_to_edit" />

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_big_margin">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewDefault"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/tax_jurisdiction" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTaxJurisdiction"
                style="@style/EditTextDefault"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_small_margin"
                android:hint="@string/tap_to_edit" />

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_big_margin">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewDefault"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/tax_registration" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextTaxRegistration"
                style="@style/EditTextDefault"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_small_margin"
                android:hint="@string/tap_to_edit" />

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/LayoutTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_big_margin">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TextViewDefault"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/driver_license_no" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextDriverLicenseNo"
                style="@style/EditTextDefault"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_small_margin"
                android:hint="@string/tap_to_edit" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubmit"
        style="@style/ButtonLight"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_medium_margin"
        android:text="@string/submit_changes"/>
</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: Prefer `FrameLayout` to `RelativeLayout`, especially when used at the top of the view hierarchy. `RelativeLayout` has to perform 2 measure passes instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.g. a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout to do this

Answer (score 0):

1. the outermost `LinearLayout` should be assigned attribute `android:orientation="vertical"`
2. `ScrollView` should be assigned attribute `android:layout_gravity="fill"`
3. `Button` should be moved out of the inner `LinearLayout` and `ScrollView` and positioned after the `ScrollView` before the outermost `LinearLayout` closing tag
4. `Button` should be assigned attribute `android:layout_gravity="bottom"`